# Call Stored Procedure in View ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've already made a stored procedure and I've called it in Controller, then the next problem is when I called this method below in view class I got error, anyone can help ?

```
public ListResponse<ViewStoredGraphRow> GetDataGraph()
{
    using (var connection = SqlConnections.NewFor<TryGraphRow>())
    {
       var data = connection.Query<Item>("StoreGraph",
            param: new
            {
                StartDate = 2018 - 07 - 07,
                EndDate = 2018 - 07 - 09
            },
            commandType: System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure);

        TestPesan tp = new TestPesan();

        var response = new ListResponse<ViewStoredGraphRow>();
        response.Entities = (List<ViewStoredGraphRow>)data;

        return response;
    }
}
```

and this is my error

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Avoid putting custom methods that belongs to view page inside controller classes (they're not intended for instantiation with `new` keyword). You can declare another class and put `GetDataGraph()` method there.

Answer (score 1):

No problem. Once your view is rendering, your controller has already been instantiated. You don't need another instance of it, just grab a reference to the existing one. So, instead of doing this in your view:

```
var data = new DashboardController().GetDataGraph();
```

Do this:

```
var controller = ViewContext.Controller as DashboardController;
var data = controller.GetDataGraph();
```

Good luck!